# Three.js error with require

Tags: javascript, three.js, requirejs

This is my first time experimenting with Three.js and Require js. I'm trying to load an Obj and Mtl file using the OBJMTLoader. I get timeout errors in console with my current setup:

```
require({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    // three.js should have UMD support soon, but it currently does not
    shim: { 
      'vendor/three': { exports: 'THREE' }, 
      'vendor/MTLLoader': { exports: 'MTLLoader'},
      'vendor/OBJMTLLoader': { deps: ['MTLLoader'], exports: 'OBJMTLLoader'}

       }
}, [
    'vendor/three',
    'vendor/MTLLoader',
    'vendor/OBJMTLLoader'

], function(THREE, OBJMTLLoader) {



var scene, camera, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();


function init() {

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;


    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 20000);
    camera.position.set(0,6,1000);
    scene.add(camera);


     window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
          HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
      renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });

     var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
     light.position.set(-100,200,100);
     scene.add(light);

     var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
          if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
          }
        };

        // var onError = function ( xhr ) {
        // };


        loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load( '/obj/Shoes_Air_Jordans_4.obj', '/obj/Shoes_Air_Jordans_4.mtl', function ( object ) {

          object.position.y = - 80;
          scene.add( object );

        }, onProgress );

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha:true});
    renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x333F47, 1);

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

});
```

I used this generator for my three js experiment https://github.com/timmywil/generator-threejs

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your .obj file as .txt
Try to load the file as .txt

'/obj/Shoes_Air_Jordans_4.txt'

EDIT:

You should also open it not in local. Threejs obj loader cannot load files in local. Use a software as hfs or load your html file on a domain

Comment: It's being run on a server. What do you mean change the obj file to txt? What about the mtl file? I think the issue is in my require function up top.

Comment: I mean that it could be a problem about mime type. Rename the .obj in .txt is a workaround, but you also can create a webconfig with the mimetype of obj files